# Simple probabilities problem

Tags: combinatorics

A student studying for a vocabulary test knows the meanings of 12 words from a list of 20 words. If the
test contains 10 words from the study list, what is the probability that at least 8 of the words on the test are
words that the student knows?

<>

I have been trying to solve it, but I just can't get it right.

Comment: See the *hypergeometric distribution*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the hypergeometric distribution we have:

$$P(X = k) = \dfrac{\begin{pmatrix} K \\ k \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} N - K \\ n - k \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} N \\ n \end{pmatrix}}$$
where $N (= 20)$ is the population size, $K ( = 12)$ is the number of successes, $n (= 10)$ is the number of draws, and $k$ is the number of observed successes. From this, we want to find $P(10) + P(9) + P(8)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!